# React Native : undefined is not an object

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am currently learning React Native.

I just a built a very simple app to test out the Button component.

When I click on the button component the console log is printed as expected.
But after printing out the console log it pops out the following error.

```
**undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this2.btnPress().bind')**
```

I am not sure what is wrong ?

Can anyone let me know what I am doing wrong ?

```
 import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

    export default class App extends React.Component {

     btnPress() {
       console.log("Fn Button pressed");
     }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="this is a test"
              onPress={()=> this.btnPress().bind(this)} />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking the function instead of passing a reference through `bind`.
loose the `()`.
And you should not wrap it with an arrow function as [bind is already returning a new function instance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

```
onPress={this.btnPress.bind(this)} />
```

By the way, this will return and create a function instance on each render, you should do it once in the `constructor` (which runs only once):

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.btnPress = this.btnPress.bind(this);
    }
     btnPress() {
       console.log("Fn Button pressed");
     }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="this is a test"
              onPress={this.btnPress} />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Or use an arrow function which uses a lexical context for `this`:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

     btnPress = () => {
       console.log("Fn Button pressed");
     }

      render() {
        return (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Button title="this is a test"
              onPress={this.btnPress} />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: I know its weird..but after replacing "this.btnPress().bind.(this)" with "this.btnPress.bind(this)" nothing happens (no console log is printed). But the error has disappeared. Any ideas as to why this could happen ?

Comment: i'm sorry i had a typo you don't need the arrow function with this syntax. i will fix my answer. this is the correct  syntax `onPress={this.btnPress.bind(this)} />` bind will return a new function hence you don't need to wrap it inside another function